# Why I can't input data into char array from struct?

Tags: c++

I've got a problem with my code or compiler...I don't know...When I input some chars into the struct char array, in the output, some arrays have other data that shouldn't really be there. It would be great if you could help me. Thank you!

If you look closely on the Year line(in bold): it is written www.tedbrown.com and IT SHOULD NOT BE there, it should output only the year.

OUTPUT:
name: ted

surname: brown

number: 123456

Email: tedb@gmail.com

job: mechanic

Day: 129

Month: 9

Year: **2019www.tedbrown.com**

Web: www.tedbrown.com

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

struct s_data
{
    char Day[2];
    char Month[2];
    char Year[4];
    //8
};
//75+8=83
struct s_contact
{
    char name[10];
    char surname[10];
    char number[10];
    char email[15];
    char job[15];
    s_data data;
    char web[15];
    //75
};

void input_contact(s_contact &temp)
{
    string tempS;
    fflush(stdin);
    cout<<"Enter name:"<<endl;
    cin>>tempS;
    strcpy(temp.name, tempS.c_str());
    cout<<"Enter surname:"<<endl;
    cin>>tempS;
    strcpy(temp.surname, tempS.c_str());
    cout<<"Enter number:"<<endl;
    cin>>tempS;
    strcpy(temp.number, tempS.c_str());
    cout<<"Enter email:"<<endl;
    cin>>tempS;
    strcpy(temp.email, tempS.c_str());
    cout<<"Enter job:"<<endl;
    cin>>tempS;
    strcpy(temp.job, tempS.c_str());
    cout<<"Enter Day:"<<endl;
    cin>>tempS;
    strcpy(temp.data.Day, tempS.c_str());
    cout<<"Enter Month:"<<endl;
    cin>>tempS;
    strcpy(temp.data.Month, tempS.c_str());
    cout<<"Enter Year:"<<endl;
    cin>>tempS;
    strcpy(temp.data.Year, tempS.c_str());
    cout<<"Enter web:"<<endl;
    cin>>tempS;
    strcpy(temp.web, tempS.c_str());
}
int main()
{
    s_contact temp;
    input_contact(temp);
    cout<<endl<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"OUTPUT:"<<endl;
    cout<<"name: "<<temp.name<<endl;
    cout<<"surname: "<<temp.surname<<endl;
    cout<<"number: "<<temp.number<<endl;
    cout<<"Email: "<<temp.email<<endl;
    cout<<"job: "<<temp.job<<endl;
    cout<<"Day: "<<temp.data.Day<<endl;
    cout<<"Month: "<<temp.data.Month<<endl;
    cout<<"Year: "<<temp.data.Year<<endl;
    cout<<"Web: "<<temp.web<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to post the input...here it is: Enter name:
ted
Enter surname:
brown
Enter number:
123456
Enter email:
tedb@gmail.com
Enter job:
mechanic
Enter Day:
12
Enter Month:
9
Enter Year:
2019
Enter web:
www.tedbrown.com

Comment: This is C++. Do everything you can to avoid using C-style character buffers like `char name[10]` and instead use `std::string name`. You do not want to be battling character buffer overflow issues or using `strcpy` and manual memory management. In fact, you should really never, ever use `strcpy`. Always use one with a buffer size limiter *if you must* work with C strings.

Comment: `char Year[4];` Not enough space for 4 chars plus `'\0'`.

Comment: Why are you using `char` for numerical values like `Year`? Don't do that. Use an `int`, or even better, a [proper time type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono).

Comment: I understand, but I've got to use binary files later on so my teacher said that we must use char arrays...so I've got no choice

Comment: Teachers like this are *the absolute worst*. Do what you can to survive this course, but keep in mind, this is **the exact opposite of how C++ code should be written**. Tip: Use `char*` and `strdup` to populate your structure. This will always size the buffer correctly. You can always serialize C++ strings by implementing simple stream operators for your various structures, meaning you can read and write from "binary" files. This is actually super easy if you take some time to think about the type of data you're working with.

Comment: Also if you must use character buffers, why not make them `char name[65535]` out of protest? Reason being that 15 is way too tiny to be even remotely useful in most cases, especially for things like email addresses.

Comment: Use `std::string` for strings when you have them inside the program. You can write and read it as null terminated strings to/from disk later.

Comment: Guys, you literally saved me...the problem was that the size of the year array was too small, I forgot about '\0' ...I appreciate all of your ideas, thank you VERY MUCH!

Comment: @AestheticCode Note that _all_ arrays in `s_data` are too small. :-)

Comment: Yes, I've changed them all...

Comment: Good - and the arrays in `s_contact` are very small too. Since you are using `strcpy` to unconditionally copy from a `std::string` to your arrays, you will notice runtime problems later when someone tries using the program. Take a look at `strncpy` and make sure you leave room for a terminating `\0`.

Comment: ... like the web address you try to store won't fit. You can store `www.tedbrown.c` at most.

Comment: You're right, I'm trying right now to implement strncpy...I didn't know it existed before...

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` causes undefined behaviour

Comment: @AestheticCode If you stick with `char[]`'s, you could make a function template to extract each array's size and use that when you populate the array. Example: https://godbolt.org/z/ddrtst (updated example)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the interaction between this definition:

```
struct s_data
{
    char Day[2];
    char Month[2];
    char Year[4];
    //8
};
```

And this output:

```
 cout<<"Year: "<<temp.data.Year<<endl;
```

With a side effect caused by this ordering:

```
struct s_contact
{
...
    s_data data;
    char web[15];
...
};
```

In s_data, you have not provided space for string terminators (the 0-byte that marks the end of a text). Your outputs are string based, which means they will spit out all data until a 0-terminator is hit.

Day outputs as "Day: 129" because there is no 0 terminator between day & month; there happens to be one after month only because your data is a single digit.  That terminator ends both the Day and Month string outputs.  Same thing happens with Year, but what lies immediately following "2019" happens to be a web address, which is much more noticeable.

This can be fixed by increasing the sizes in s_data to:

```
struct s_data
{
    char Day[3];
    char Month[3];
    char Year[5];
};
```

Or, alternately, if s_data is a format you must work with, you may need to do some special processing to ensure you only output the values you want.

**Side Note**: If you fill in your data fields in a different order than they are declared, you can get some really strange effects -- what you see now is zero-terminators overwritten by good data, but initialize out of order and you'll see 0-terminators wiping out existing data.  ( Ex: Set the web address & then the year -- you'll lose the entire web address because you'll put a 0 over it's first byte when you fill in the 4-digit year ).

Comment: Side note: Prefer [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) over a `char` array if permitted. `string` makes sure the data fits (when used correctly) and has an impressive library of support functions.

Answer (score -4):

Just change the following piece of code from :

```
struct s_contact
{
char name[10];
char surname[10];
char number[10];
char email[15];
char job[15];
s_data data;
char web[15];
//75
}
```

to

```
struct s_contact
{
char name[10];
char surname[10];
char number[10];
char email[15];
char job[15];
//s_data data; *It shouldnot be here.*
char web[15];
s_data data; //*It should be here*
//75
}
```

This is because of the memory allocation technique.

[U can go through this for some references.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct)

**I hope the code should run now properly.**

Comment: No, that's not what's causing the problem OP has.

Comment: Yes, i tried it - and if you had read the comments above it should be obvious that's not what is causing it.

Comment: This is a code-only answer and at the end of the day code-only answers are good for little more than leveling up one's copy-paste skills. To salvage this answer, explain what the problem was ("it should not be here" is insufficient explanation.) and how your proposed fix solves the problem. Once you've done this, you'll probably find that you have only traded a visible and known problem for a hidden problem.

Comment: This solves nothing, just sweeps the problem under the rug so it may not be as noticeable.